# How to parse Nested Json Array in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

{
  "Error": null,
  "InternalError": null,
  "IsSuccessful": true,
  "Message": null,
  "Branches": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Years": [
        {
          "Id": 6,
          "Year": "2015 - 2016"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: what you are using Volly, Retrofit ??.....what you have tried ??

Comment: Used normal http client..

Comment: the bellow answer of mdDroid is right ..go with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONOBject("Your Response");
if(mainObj != null){
JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("Branches");
if(list != null){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
        JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
        if(elem != null){
            JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("Years");
            if(prods != null){

                  //Your Code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```